# Pandas DataFrame Date Series to List conversion

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called "signal_data" that has data as below

```
Pressure   DateTime             Temp
3025       2016-04-01 00:17:00  TTY    
3019       2016-04-01 00:17:00  TTY    
3019       2016-04-01 00:17:00  TTY    
.....          
3025       2016-05-01 10:17:00  TTY    
.....
```

I am trying to get unique values from DateTime column and convert to list.
When I apply the following command, the datetime values are getting converted to int but not datetime.

```
signal_data['DateTime'].unique().tolist()

[1459469820000000000,    
 1459516620000000000,    
 1459527420000000000,    
 ...    
 1462087020000000000]
```

May I know why this is happening and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: what does `print(signal_data['DateTime'].dtypes)` say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure why Pandas is implicity casting it. However, you can fix it by doing the following (assuming you have done `import pandas as pd`):

```
pd.to_datetime(signal_data['DateTime'].unique()).tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks.. it works.. also the following works as well

Comment: list(set([x for x in signal_data['DateTime']]))

Comment: You wouldn't need the list comprehension inside the call to `set()`. Just call it directly on the Series.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `unique()`, it returns a numpy array of type datetime. Numpy datetime is not python's fundamental datatype. When you convert it to list it trys to change the datatype to pythonic version. So you get the int. So use `list(..)` to keep the datetime as is. i.e

```
list(df['DateTime'].unique()) 
[numpy.datetime64('2016-04-01T00:17:00.000000000')]

OR convert it to series and then tolist()

pd.Series(df['DateTime'].unique()).tolist()
[Timestamp('2016-04-01 00:17:00')]
```