# Why does pandas dataframe tolist return datetime as values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

So I have this pandas dataframe I want to save in a postgres database.I want to keep the datetime as timestamp with timezone.

```
df.set_index(['datetime', 'area_id'], inplace=True)
df = df.tz_localize('Asia/Tokyo', level=0)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(df[0].values)
```

And I get

> [Timestamp('2018-04-01 00:00:00+0900', tz='Asia/Tokyo') 1 1 3000.0]

however when I do this the dataframe become values even though I want the datetime.
What I want 
[('2018-04-01 00:00:00+0900',1, 1, 3000.0)]

However when I ran this code

```
d = list(zip(*[df[c].values.tolist() for c in df])
print(d)
```

I get values in stead of datetime.

> (1522508400000000000, 1, 1, 3000.0)

what I have tried so far.

```
df['datetime']=df['datetime'].dt.to_pydatetime()
```

but it didn't work.
I found this solution [Pandas DataFrame Date Series to List conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124639/pandas-dataframe-date-series-to-list-conversion)
but it  wasn't helpful in my case. It shows only one particular columns while I want to do it for all the columns.

Comment: Please post a snippet of code which produces one or two rows of your actual DataFrame and a few columns, and tell us *exactly* what you want the output to look  like.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your date column to strings first:

```
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].apply(str)
```

Then:

```
df.values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any info on what the dataframe looks like, and assuming the output needs to be a list of tuples and the `datetime` part of the tuple needs to actually be `datetime`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],
                   'b':['foo','bar','foobar'],
                   'dt_var':np.array(['2018-01-01T12:00', '2018-02-03T00:00:01', '1018-09-01T15:15'], dtype='datetime64')})
s = df['dt_var'].dt.to_pydatetime()
cols_to_zip = list(df.columns.values)
cols_to_zip.remove('dt_var')


d = [(*x,y) for x in df[cols_to_zip].values for y in s ]

print(type(d[0][2]))
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

I would still use John Zwinck's answer though - make them strings and reconvert them after if you need to.