# Datetime Automatically Converted to Int

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have a series that contains datetime data.

**When I want to use `Series.unique().tolist()`, it seems that the datetime was automatically converted to an int.**

Please see the example below. I now realized that it is not necessary as I can iterate over `Series.unique()`, but just out of curiosity does anyone know why?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I guess you may find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124639/pandas-dataframe-date-series-to-list-conversion).

Long story short: you are trying to convert from `numpy.datetime64` type (output of `.unique()`), which is not present in vanilla python, so it is being cast to int.

Workaround is using `list()`:

```
list(sch['Datetime_sch'].unique())
```